# How To Center Align the Title Bar text In Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a Windows Form Application. I want to Align the Text to Center or say to Right  of Title Bar of Form. How can I do it ??

Comment: Don't think anything is built-in, check this out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93959/WinForm-Extended

Answer (score 16):

It can be done with custom form - you will have to create your own title bar. See V4Vendettas comment;

Other approach ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/260240/Windows-Form-Title-Bar-Text-alignment)) - is to create your own handler for form resize and insert there followong code. It will add appropriate amount of spaces from the left size of text. However you will have to add form.Refresh() and call that method in form.Load; also your window will have "..." as a text in task bar.

```
private void UpdateTextPosition()
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    Double startingPoint = (this.Width / 2) - (g.MeasureString(this.Text.Trim(), this.Font).Width / 2);
    Double widthOfASpace = g.MeasureString(" ", this.Font).Width;
    String tmp = " ";
    Double tmpWidth = 0;

    while ((tmpWidth + widthOfASpace) < startingPoint)
    {
       tmp += " ";
       tmpWidth += widthOfASpace;
    }

    this.Text = tmp + this.Text.Trim();
}
```

Comment: In unicode environment(mine is Chinese OS and Chinese VS2010), the width of tmp ends up to be much bigger than count*width of space.

Comment: I tried to edit the response and add "t" to the mpWidth inside the while loop. However, it won't let me, since the change has to have at least 6 characters. Maybe user JleruOHep can change this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a text that's inside a control (Like a label), you can edit the property named "TextAlign" to accomplish what you want inside Windows Form Designer.

Or programmatically,

```
Label.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

If you're talking about aligning the text of the title bar, there is no way to do this through Winforms. You will have to use something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93959/WinForm-Extended

Comment: how can I add Label or Textbox Control to Windows Form Title Bar in C#

Comment: You have to create your own form - without built-in title bar, but with your own

Answer (score 0):

```
 Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        double fw = this.Width; // form width
        double tw = g.MeasureString(this.Text.Trim(), this.Font).Width; \\ text width
        double rp = (fw - tw) / 2;
        int tt = Convert.ToInt32(rp); 
        string st = " ";
        st = st.PadRight(tt / 3);
        this.Text = st + this.Text.Trim();
```

Comment: I'd suggest changing your variable names to provide a bit more context as to what you're actually doing, or at least provide a description with your code.

Answer (score -3):

Inside Windows Form Designer. Make the changes like `this.lable1.AutoSize = false`;

Then:

```
this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```