# Main form text aligning in vb.net form

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, text, alignment

I want to align my main form text to the centre of the title bar. I have no idea how I would start this. I have also "googled" this problem and have found no solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947314/how-to-center-align-the-title-bar-text-in-windows-form

Comment: The title bar of a window is painted by Windows.  The days of intercepting WM_NCPAINT to do it yourself are long gone, much too complicated to deal with the user's visual styles and glass preferences.  A simple way to get the text in the center is to update your machine to Windows 8 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with the caveats mentioned in my comment link:

```
Public Class Form1
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CenterMe()
 End Sub
 Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    CenterMe()
 End Sub
 Private Sub CenterMe()
    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Dim startingPoint As Double = (Me.Width / 2) - (g.MeasureString(Me.Text.Trim, Me.Font).Width / 2)
    Dim widthOfASpace As Double = g.MeasureString(" ", Me.Font).Width
    Dim tmp As String = " "
    Dim tmpWidth As Double = 0
    Do
        tmp += " "
        tmpWidth += widthOfASpace
    Loop While (tmpWidth + widthOfASpace) < startingPoint

    Me.Text = tmp & Me.Text.Trim & tmp

    Me.Refresh()
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: hmm i threw 2 textboxes and a button on a winform and it's not flickering anything for me..