# How to give a different color to my form text programatically

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows

i would like to give the `my username in red color` in the centre of the my form. Please see my image. I already have my application name on the left hand side and my username in the centre.. I just need to make my username in red color

[image]

How can i give this??

Codes:-

```
    var someNewStr1 = new string(' ', 100);
    this.Text = "Publisher 1.0.0.0" + someNewStr1 + "USERNAME1";
    //i need the user name to be shown in red colour how can i do this
```

Comment: that is not the form *name* pictured, just the form **.Text**

Comment: @Plutonix i need to give exactly on the centre of the form

Comment: Put a label in the center of the form, and set the text on the label. But that has nothing to do with the form name.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11947314/1070452

Comment: Your body and title appear to be mismatched currently, one talks about adding a title, the other changing a color. By changing color, do you mean on the window chrome itself?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i need the text of form to be in different color,... `Publisher 1.0.0.0` to be in `black colour` and i need the next `USERNAME1` in bold red colour

Comment: Could you the expected text via an image editor? That way we can see what you are really trying to do.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to change your question to something entirely different...

Comment: @DavidLibido actually i meant to post this. sorry. do you know.. i tried this `this.Text.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;` but its giving error.. called `Error string' does not contain a definition for 'ForeColor' and no extension method 'ForeColor' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: In .Net you can't change the form title text colors as far as I know. The .Text property is just a string, which is why you get the error

Comment: You can simply create a small borderless form with the red title and place it over the right spot of the real form, keeping it sy'ched with each move&eresize.. no big hassle but still not worth it imo..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extremely fiddly problem and can't be done out of the of the box.

You'll either have to try and draw on the non-client area of the form and capture all the redraw messages, which I'm not sure will even work 100% (however it might).

Or resort to even more extreme tactics and use a borderless form and redraw the title bar from and border from scratch.

Additionally the second approach is prone to all sorts of issues with system settings and implementing the standard title bar features, i.e. you'll have to implement all the default windows styles and default behaviors.

At this point you really do have to ask your self whether your coding time is going to be better spent in other areas, or with a slightly different solution.

I.e. Why not put the client name in a status bar, or right aligned in a tool bar.

However just for academic purposes, there is a Codeplex article that does show you all the hacks needed to achieve what you desire (there are too many and too much code for the purposes of this answer).

Please note: while the below link is slightly off topic it does touch the areas you need to do both scenarios.

[**Extending Form with Non-Client Area Painting**](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Painting%20NonClient%20Area)

I hope this convinces you, it's probably not worth your while.